# What types of algorithms does Google Cloud Vision API use to perform image annotations?

Tags: algorithm, annotations, google-cloud-vision

I would like to have a superficial idea about the methods used by Google to perform image annotation and how these methods are related to each other. I couldn't find anywhere else this information, except some user's guesses, and I would like to have something more reliable.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe much of the API's backend is done with `tensorflow`. (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/explore-the-galaxy-of-images-with-cloud-vision-api, https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/02/google-cloud-vision-api-available-to-all)

--> I'm guessing that there's some big ol' deep convolutional neural networks trained from google images, implemented with `tensorflow` (https://www.tensorflow.org/, http://kaptur.co/what-googles-new-open-source-tensorflow-and-cloud-vision-api-mean-for-photo-app-developers/).

Some `tensorflow` info about deep convolutional neural networks: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html